# Converting string to date

Tags: php, sql, database, function, date

I have the dates in the table like this

```
2012-08-27 
2011-01-12 
2011-08-27  
2010-01-12
2010-08-27
```

The given input is a string like "Fall 2012", "Spring 2015". The rule is the day of 27th always means FALL and the day of 12th always means SPRING.

I need if the given string for example "Fall 2012" output '2012-08-27' and if the given string "Spring 2010" I can print out this date '2010-01-12'

This is my code, but this will be too long. I can take the year in one string and the season in another string. For example `$year=2012` and `$season=Fall`.

```
<?php

$string="Fall 2013";

if ($string=="Fall 2012"){
echo '2012-08-27'; 
}elseif ($string=="Spring 2012")

{
echo '2012-01-12'; 

}elseif ($string=="Fall 2013")
{
echo '2013-08-27'; 

}elseif ($string=="Fall 2014")
{
echo '2014-08-27'; 
}


?>
```

Comment: Have you tried something ? Where is your code?

Comment: ATLEAST SHOW SOME CODE LIKE CONNECTION TO DB AND HOW YOU ARE DOING IT?

Comment: What database are you using?

Comment: I need to convert the string first to date then I will start searching the date base. My problem is with converting. I have the code to convert from date to string  I use sql

Comment: @GordonLinoff I knew it when I retag the question with `SQL` you're here :D Now if OP will show his real code he will get some real help!

Comment: @HussainAlmalki 1. Please show us your **full** and **real** code! 2. What DB do you have? 3. Please consider to read this: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask 4. Make sure you add error reporting to the top of your file(s): `<?php
  ini_set("display_errors", 1);
  error_reporting(E_ALL);
 ?>` 5. It doesn't matter if your code works or what so ever! That's why you're here, just post your attempts!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this function:

```php
function changeSeasonToDate($string) {
    $season = [
        '~Spring (\d{4})~' => '\1-01-12',
        '~Fall (\d{4})~' => '\1-08-27',
    ];
    foreach ($season as $pattern => $date) {
        $string = preg_replace($pattern, $date, $string);
    }
    return $string;
}
```

Example of the use:

```php
echo changeSeasonToDate('Spring 2013'); # 2013-01-12
echo changeSeasonToDate('Fall 2015');   # 2015-08-27
```

<kbd>[**demo**](https://eval.in/308625)</kbd>

Comment: I just accepted the answer. Thank you again for your great help.

Answer (score 0):

---

### MSSQL verison

```sql
declare @input as varchar(10)
set @input = 'Fall 2011'

    select
        id, date_column
    from
        tbl1
    where 
        year(date_column) = right(@input,4)
    group by 
        id, date_column
    having 
        (CASE 
            WHEN day(date_column) = 27 Then 'Fall' 
            else 'Spri' End) = left(@input,4)
```

---

### MySQL version

```sql
SELECT 
id, date_column 
FROM 
tbl1 
where 
year(date_column) = right('Fall 2010',4) 
group by id, date_column 
having 
(CASE WHEN day(date_column) = 27 Then 'Fall' else 'Spri' End) = left('Fall 2010',4)
```